# ant : apply executable when output file doesn't exist

Tags: ant

I try to create a ant target which processes some GLSL shaders from an input directory, output them in another folder. And I'd like to avoid the processing if the output file already exists.

The executable I use can either take an output directory argument, or directly the output file path.

Currently, I have :

```
<target name="optimize_programs">
    <apply executable="TOOLS/glsl_processor" dir="." verbose="true" >
        <srcfile/>
        <arg value="-output_directory=OUTPUT/PROGRAMS/" />
        <fileset dir="INPUT/PROGRAMS/OPENGLES2" includes="**/*.glfx" />
        <flattenmapper />
    </apply>
</target>
```

The shaders are correctly processed, but the problem is they are processed each time, even when the output file already exists.

I suspect this is because the flattenmapper is not aware of the glsl_processor output.

I've tried to use  to tell the glsl_processor where to output the file :

```
<target name="optimize_programs">
    <apply executable="TOOLS/glsl_processor" dir="." verbose="true" >
        <srcfile/>
        <targetfile/>
        <fileset dir="INPUT/PROGRAMS/OPENGLES2" includes="**/*.glfx" />
        <flattenmapper />
    </apply>
</target>
```

But I don't know how to make targetfile point to the output folder.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well the answer is actually pretty simple:

```
<target name="optimize_programs">
    <apply executable="TOOLS/glsl_processor" dir="INPUT/PROGRAMS/OPENGLES2/" dest="OUTPUT/PROGRAMS" verbose="true" >
        <targetfile/>
        <srcfile/>
        <fileset dir="INPUT/PROGRAMS/OPENGLES2" includes="**/*.glfx" />
        <mapper type="glob" from="*.glfx" to="*.glfx"/>
    </apply>
</target>
```

I was just missing to fill the **dest** attribute of the **apply** task.